# Chronicle Map single writer, non-replicated crash resilience

Tags: chronicle-map

We have a relatively simple application that needs to persist the state of the items it manages on a regular basis for recovery purposes. For performance reasons we need this write to be extremely fast. We had thought to use Chronicle Map against a local file system for this purpose. My question is to what extent can I count on the integrity of that cache in various crash scenarios, e.g. application crashes, JVM crashes, or OS crashes. The only reading we will perform will be on recovery, other than that we will only be writing. Our hope is that as persistence of the map is managed by the OS, we would have some measure of resilience from application and JVM.

We've tried a variety of crash scenarios and so far it seems resilient but would like to know if there are scenarios we are missing. Clearly if the application is in the middle of a map write that would cause corruption. If so, how extensive would the corruption be?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.